# Why does $y \text{~} N(X \beta, \sigma^2 V)$ $\implies$ $M^T y \text{~} N(0, \sigma^2 M^T V M)$

Tags: reml

Why does $$y \text{~} N(X \beta, \sigma^2 V)$$ $\implies$ $$M^T y \text{~} N(0, \sigma^2 M^T V M)$$?

When $M^T X=0$ and $M^T M = I$.

Comment: multivariate mgf?

Comment: @BCLC What, where?

Comment: mavavilj, I was thinking to just compute E and Var of $M^Ty$ but how do we know it's still normal?

Comment: [affine transforms of normals are normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_normal_deviates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See 6.2 in [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf)

$$E[M^Ty] = M^TE[y] = M^TX\beta = 0 \ \beta = 0$$

$$Var[M^Ty] = M^TVar(y)(M^T)^T$$

$$=M^T\sigma^2VM$$

as to why we still have normality: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332441/affine-transformation-applied-to-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-what